# PHP checking if query returns anything error

Tags: php, mysql

I've been pondering about this for a while, I'm trying to see if the query wields any results and I want to do something if it doesn't return any results.

PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$passw = "";
$con = mysql_connect($host, $user, $passw);


if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$json = $_REQUEST['json'];
$json = stripslashes($json);
$jsonobj = json_decode($json);

$me = $jsonobj -> me;
$other = $jsonobj -> other;
mysql_select_db("tinyspace", $con);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE (user_id = '" .$me. "' AND user_id2 = '" .$other. "') OR (user_id2 = '" .$me. "' AND user_id1 = '" .$other. "')");

if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{

}
```

the if statement keeps giving me problems however.
Any Advice?

Comment: What's the problem? Could you give us an error message/problem explanation?

Comment: And your code is very unsafe: Look up SQL-injection.

Comment: Just as a side note: `mysql_*` is getting outdated.. `PDO` or `mysqli` is advised now.

Comment: @Veseliq it tells me that the mysql_num_rows expects a resource but is receiving a boolean.

Comment: You need to read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) **immediately**.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [*red box*](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try

```
<?php 
if($result == false){
   //what you want to do if the query returns nothing
}else{
   //handle the result
}
```

for those who think my answer is incorrect or the opposite of what is asked, please read the question from the beginning again, very carefully.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `if ($result)` instead of the opposite? The `else` ends up being "if result is false is not true" which is nothing short of confusing."

Comment: the person who asked the question said they wanted to do something if the result returned nothing, this way when the query fails or yields nothing, you can add your code in there, hence my answer

Answer (score 1):

just to be sure, how many columns do you have named `userid`? user_id, user_id1, user_id2 ?
do you mean `user_id1` in place of `user_id` in the below line, by any chance?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE (user_id = '" .$me. "' AND user_id2 = '" .$other. "') OR (user_id2 = '" .$me. "' AND user_id1 = '" .$other. "')");
```

If so, maybe thats why you aren't fetching any results.

**Edit:**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE (user_id1 = '" .$me. "' AND user_id2 = '" .$other. "') OR (user_id2 = '" .$me. "' AND user_id1 = '" .$other. "')");
```

Comment: no, I have 2 columns, 1 called user_id1 and another called user_id2

Comment: the question asks how to check whether the query returns no results, this answer doesn't satisfy the question, it should be posted as a comment

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_num_rows()` is okay to use for checking if you have results, and should work in your example..

However, if your call to  `mysql_num_rows()` doesn't work as expected (i.e. always false), it's almost always down to a problem with the query. 
`mysql_num_rows()` expects a result resource, and if there is a problem with your query, mysql_query will return a false.

You can amend your mysql_query() call to

```
mysql_query("sql here") or die(mysql_error());
```

That should give you an idea if the error lies in the query. Once you've checked your query is working as expected, your mysql_num_rows() will start functioning correctly.

Additionally, the mysql_ functions are depreceated, you should take a look at Prepared Statements http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `friends` WHERE (`user_id1` = '" .$me. "' AND `user_id2` = '" .$other. "') OR (`user_id2` = '" .$me. "' AND `user_id1` = '" .$other. "')");
```

Answer (score -1):

to simply answer your question, while it seems that while your code is potentially vulnerable, it should act as you intend.  This is what I use in my connection class

```
public function makeQuery(){
 if($result = mysqli_query($this->link, $this->sql)){
     if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0){
         while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
             $return[] = $r;
         }
         mysqli_free_result($result);
         return $return;
     }else{
         return 0;
     }
 }else{
     // db error here
 }
```

}

This assumes you feed the class some value for $sql and $link...  but you can then check for either an integer return or an array return.  if it is an integer (0), it had no rows, an array will be the returned rows.  If there is an error it will fall into the error logic (I send myself an email in this case).

Comment: I would like to know why this was voted down.  it is what I use currently, if it is not optimal I would appreciate knowing why.